# Running into an issue with PyQt5 when I attempt to run an .AppImage

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
Fatal Python error: PyQt5.QtCore: Unable to embed qt.conf
Python runtime state: initialized
ValueError: character U+6b616577 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]

Current thread 0x00007fd322e62740 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1166 in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 556 in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 657 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1042 in _handle_fromlist
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This specific Python error seems to occur despite having pyqt5 installed (along with the webengine and devtools).  Is there something I'm missing that is causing this error to constantly appear?

I'm particularly curious about the `Fatal Python error: PyQt5.QtCore: Unable to embed qt.conf` message and wonder if that's the key to solving this error.

If anyone could provide guidance on what dependency or package I might be missing, that would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm facing it with CentOS Stream 8 and conda.